# JSONArray cannot be apply to java.lang.string

Tags: android, android-json

I have this volley onResponse:

```
 public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONArray info = new JSONArray(response);

        String name = info.getString("name");
        String picture = info.getString("picture");
        Picasso.with(context).load(picture).into(profile);
        user_name.setText(name);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

the problem is that `("name")` and `("picture")` gives me JSONArray cannot be apply to java.lang.string.

What did I miss?

edit:

```
[{"name":"josh","picture":"http:\/\/192.168.0.11\/pic.png"}]
```

Comment: Can you share the response JSON, looks like "name" and "picture" values are also JSONArray and not just string.

Comment: @Shubham it is like this: `[{"name":"josh","picture":"http:\/\/ip\/pic.png"}]`

Comment: You are not Looping on the array !

Answer (score 2):

Do that to parse this response!

```
  try {
            JSONArray info = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i =0; i<info.length() ; i++) {
                JSONObject obj = info.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = obj.getString("name");
                String picture = obj.getString("picture");
                Picasso.with(context).load(picture).into(profile);
                user_name.setText(name);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment of @Atef Hares:

```
JSONArray info = new JSONArray(response);

String name = info.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
String picture = info.getJSONObject(0).getString("picture");
Picasso.with(context).load(picture).into(profile);
user_name.setText(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

change to below code.

```
try {
    JSONArray info = new JSONArray(response);

    String name = info.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
    String picture = info.getJSONObject(0).getString("picture");
    Picasso.with(context).load(picture).into(profile);
    user_name.setText(name);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```